# Is Unity 5.0 ready to use now?

Tags: 11.10, unity

It seems relatively stable in videos and it isn't like the version of Unity I'm using in 11.10 is the most rock solid either, I have to restart it once in a while.

Is there any reason I would not want to be using Unity 5.0 right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a definite answer for something that is inherently indefinite. Software has bugs and some of those only show up in a portion of use-cases.

Is it safe to use? Probably. I can't imagine it'll ever do any damage to anything and as Amith says, there's a PPA and you can purge that out with `ppa-purge` fairly easily.

Will it crash? Explode? Be more stable? Who knows. I suggest you give it a test. If it has problems make sure you post new bugs on Launchpad so that, come release, other people in your situation have a better experience.

Comment: I hear what you are saying Oli. I was just curious if it was responsible to run or the act of a mad man

Comment: I think if you wanted to do the most responsible thing you'd start your testing in 12.04 because I can't say how well a new unity version will work with older components (compiz, X, et al). But that has a lot more risk for you.

Answer (score 4):

It is somewhat well stable and also you can run it without risks in 11.10.

In case something goes wrong, use the command `ppa-purge` to revert back.